# XML-File i send to the API gets encoded, how to prevent that?

Tags: c#, api, oauth, oauth-1.0a, devdefined-oauth

I am using an API to download a XML File and read it, which works perfectly.

Now i want to add something and upload a new version of this XML-File, but it gets encoded and one cant read it with an XML Reader.
It looks like this:

> %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3C

I know i could just encode it using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`, but i would like to have a better solution, because the XML gets stored this way on the server which is not what i want.

Here the code i use to send the request:

```
string test = xmlFile.Insert(index, topic);
// byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(test);
// test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

MessageBox.Show(test);

IConsumerRequest getFileRequest = consumerSession
    .Request()
    .ForMethod("PUT")
    .ForUri(new Uri(apiEndpoint + "/1/documents/" + documentid + "/upload"))
    .WithBody(test)
    .SignWithToken(accessToken);

string getFileResponse = getFileRequest.ToString();
```

I use the `DevDefined.OAuth.Framework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, gotta do it like this:

```
IConsumerRequest getFileRequest = consumerSession
    .Request()
    .ForMethod("PUT")
    .ForUri(new Uri(apiEndpoint + "/1/documents/" + documentid + "/upload"))
    .WithRawContent(test, Encoding.UTF8)
    .WithRawContentType("text/xml")
    .SignWithToken(accessToken);
```